# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client ext.net

Tags: firefox, ext.net

I have a user control in ext.net and a hidden field inside it which is "__DataForAddingToOutlook". This field is filled using xml writer so it has xml.
We have a functionality to add data to outlook and sync to outlook for which I am using direct methods. As soon as I call direct method I get the error
"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (cms_cpMain_winAddContactsToOutlook___DataForAddingToOutlook="

The field is filled like-

```
Private Sub ExportToControl()
    Dim oXMLWriter As XmlTextWriter = Nothing
    Dim oStream As MemoryStream = Nothing
    oStream = New MemoryStream()
    oXMLWriter = New XmlTextWriter(oStream, Encoding.UTF8)
    ReadData(oXMLWriter)
    '
    Dim stream_reader As New StreamReader(oStream)
    oStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
    __DataForAddingToOutlook.Value = stream_reader.ReadToEnd()
End Sub
```

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set ValidateRequest="false" in Page tag:

```
<%@ Page Title="" ValidateRequest="false" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>
```